# How to use forestFloor() on randomForest output from caret package?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I've been using the `forestFloor` package to visualize random forest model structure. Everything was going great until I tried to use `forestFloor()` on a random forest output from the `caret` package. I need to use `caret` instead of `randomForest` for my dataset because I have severely imbalanced classes, so using the SMOTE sampling strategy. I fixed a couple things, passing `keep.inbag=TRUE` and `keep.forest=TRUE` into `caret::train`, and then finding the `randomForest` object hidden in the `train` class object, `$finalModel`.

I still get the error:
`Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : index out of bounds`

Please see the following minimal working example, taken from the Pima Indians diabetes dataset in `mlbench`. Thank you in advance!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

other attached packages:
[1] DMwR_0.4.1          caret_6.0-70        ggplot2_2.1.0      
[4] lattice_0.20-34     forestFloor_1.9.5   randomForest_4.6-12
[7] mlbench_2.1-1

library(mlbench)
library(randomForest)
library(forestFloor)

data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
y = PimaIndiansDiabetes$diabetes
X = PimaIndiansDiabetes
X = X[,!names(X)=="diabetes"]
rf.randomForest  = randomForest(X,y,sampsize=25,ntree=5000,mtry=4,
 keep.inbag = T,keep.forest = T)

## Use forestFloor on randomForest output, works great
ff = forestFloor(rf.randomForest,X,binary_reg = T,calc_np=T)
Col = fcol(ff,cols=1,outlier.lim = 2.5)
plot(ff,col=Col,plot_GOF = T)

## Now fit random forest using SMOTE from caret package
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number=5,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     sampling = "smote")
rf.SMOTE <- train(x=X,y=y,
                      method = "rf",
                      tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 3),
                      metric = "ROC",
                      trControl = ctrl,
                      keep.inbag=TRUE,
                      keep.forest=TRUE)
rf.caret <- rf.SMOTE$finalModel

## Use forestFloor on caret output, throws error
ff = forestFloor(rf.caret,X,binary_reg = T,calc_np=T)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: Sort of... it's not the entire `caret` package, just specifically SMOTE resampling. Soren replied with a potential fix but I have not tried it yet: https://github.com/sorhawell/forestFloor/issues/22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out with help from Soren: https://github.com/sorhawell/forestFloor/issues/22.

Paraphrasing Soren: The problem is that `caret`'s version of SMOTE resamples the training data and saves it somewhere else (?). To estimate feature contributions you need to pass the same data set (X) as used for training to `forestFloor`. Feature contribution calculations with `forestFloor` rely on out-of-bag sampling and the inbag matrix to match the provided training set.

Fix: It's possible to use the `SMOTE` function in the `DMwR` package instead of using SMOTE within the `caret` package. `DMwR::SMOTE` returns the re-sampled training data that you then can put into `randomForest` and then `forestFloor`.

```
library(randomForest)
library(DMwR)
library(forestFloor)
# covar = names of covariate/feature column names (character vector)
# target = response column names (character)
X <- cbind(dat[,covar], factor(dat[,target]))
names(X) <- c(covar, target)
bin.formula <- formula(paste0(target," ~ ",paste0(covar,collapse=" + ")))
X.SMOTE <- SMOTE(bin.formula, data=X, k=5)
rf.SMOTE <- randomForest(x=X.SMOTE[,covar], y=X.SMOTE[,target], keep.inbag=T, ...)
ff.bin = forestFloor(rf.fit = rf.SMOTE, X = X.SMOTE[,covar])
```